# JavaFX: how to clear the canvas

Tags: javafx, java-canvas

Let's say I have drawn a rectangle on my canvas and I want to clean it in order to draw some other figure / polygon / arc ....

How can I do it?  I have tried it in many ways but none has worked.

I think this may work but I'm not sure:

```
GraphicsContext gc = myCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
gc.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
```

Could you tell me if this will work consistently and whether it is the standard way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The method [clearRect](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#clearRect%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) seems to be dedicated for this:

```
gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

Comment: @Roland How do I clear a rectangle inclined at an angle?

Comment: maybe this is better: gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());